Collectible effect with particles
I want to make a coin/star collectible effect like when you beat a level in the game Geometry Dash. There, the stars all fall from a pre-defined place in random directions, and after about 1 second of bouncing they get collected into another area where the total currency the user has collected is located

I also want the effect of the total collected text to go up gradually as the stars and orbs (blue circles) are collected.
The thing is, even though I can create the effect of the stars falling down and bounce around, I can't pull them into the top right corner. Because of that, I also don't know how to make the total collected count go up gradually (I could use Tween such as LeanTween to increase the number with easing, but I would still need to calculate when the number increasing should start and when it should end, and it may look weird if sometimes more stars are collected in a period and the total counter still goes up by the same amount).
I have tried using Particle Force Fields, but could not get ut to work, and I think there us no option to count up when a particle gets destroyed, so I should not use particles. What should I use instead?
Thanks for any help :)

What's your question? It's not clear with what aspect you need help.

The amount of stars is not that much, you could use some simple image, a physics material with a bounce factor and after around 2s move the stars to the fixed corner

So you mean a basic GameObject with a Rigidbody2D? How would I move that in front of the canvas?

Create a Wind Zone in your top-right corner and use External Forces module to apply it to your particles.
